# Checking for forward dates in data

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run a query that will pick up days from here on out. Basically, today, tomorrow, and so forth.

Here is my code..

```
$dateNow = date('Y-m-d');

$where .= ' AND `mb_sanctions`.`StartDate` > \'$dateNow\'';
```

I keep getting the variable back on my developer tools..where am I going wrong?

Comment: `SELECT field FROM table WHERE DATE(column) >= CURDATE()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead you can try this:

```
$where .= ' AND `mb_sanctions`.`StartDate` > CURRENT_DATE';
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `stardate` is a date column, why not just use:

```
$where .= ' AND `mb_sanctions`.`StartDate` > now()';
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your query should be:

```
$where .= ' AND `mb_sanctions`.`StartDate` > ''' . $dateNow . '''';
```

You're returning $datenow as the result because you're not concatenating the date onto the string, you're returning the literal of that variable.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `DATE_ADD( )` for that, example:

```
DATE(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

the query above outputs tomorrow's date.

**[More on this LINK about DATE_ADD( )](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp)**

or you can also do it like this:

```
$where .= ' AND DATE(`mb_sanctions`.`StartDate`) > DATE(CURDATE())';
```